# Error on my __construct()

Tags: php, pdo

Hi guys I am having trouble on my code. Please see below my current code.
What I want to achieve is to set my database fields (id,name,type) as public attributes.

```
Ex:
public $id;
public $name;
public $type;
```

I hope you can help me with this. :)

Errors:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Animals::__construct() in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pdo_intro\index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pdo_intro\index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pdo_intro\index.php on line 20
```

My Current Code

```
class Animals{

public $db_fields;
private $dbh;

public function __construct($dbh){

$this->dbh = $dbh;

$this->db_fields = $this->get_fields();

foreach($this->db_fields as $field){
$this->$field = "";
}
}

public function get_fields(){
$q = $this->dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE animals");
$q->execute();
$db_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

return $db_fields;
}

public function capitalizeType($t){
return ucwords($t);
}
}

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';
/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';
/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '';
/*** mysql database***/
$dbname = 'animals';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$animal = new Animals($dbh);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM animals";
$result = $dbh->query($sql);

while ($r = $result->fetchObject('animals')){
echo $animal->capitalizeType($r->animal_type) . "<br />";
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I tried __construct($dbh="") and still the error is

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\pdo_intro\index.php on line 20
```

Comment: Does using `function __construct(&$dbh) {` help??

Answer (score 3):

Your problem appears to be here,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$animal = new Animals($dbh);
```

Your database connection is not working, check your username and password etc. If $dbh does not return an object then the 1st parameter for the construct will be empty, setting a default value will not fix it since the rest of your code depends on the value passed to be a object and "" is not an object.

Comment: I put echo "Connected" once the database is successfully connected and it is showing.

Comment: right after the database connecting put this var_dump($dbh); and post the output.

Comment: I think the error is in while loop because when I comment/remove it.
The error is not showing. :/
I still didn't figured it where on the while loop is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while ($r = $result->fetchObject('animals')){
    echo $animal->capitalizeType($r->animal_type) . "<br />";
}
```

You are fetching data into `Animals` class, however PDO while creating new object does not pass anything to it's constructor.

Also you don't have to worry about properties, PDO will create them for you if they are not present.